How to Resolve HTTP Errors When Pushing a CodeIgniter 4 Project to GitHub?
I'm experiencing an issue with pushing my CodeIgniter 4 project to GitHub. The error message indicates an HTTP 400 response with a curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 5 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL error, or sometimes a curl 55 Recv failure: Connection was reset. This problem persists even after attempting different fixes such as switching to SSH instead of HTTPS and checking network stability. The push seems to start correctly, but ultimately fails with a message indicating that the remote end hung up unexpectedly. I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue effectively.
Despite following several troubleshooting steps, including increasing the http.postBuffer size and updating Git, I keep facing an error during the push process

Are you pushing with large zips or video files after commit ?
